# Does Hilbert 90 need the extension to be Galois?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I read about Hilbert 90 in Morandi's *Fields and Galois Theory* (GTM 167).

> Let $K/F$ be a finite Galois extension. Let $G=\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$. Define a crossed homomorphism $f\colon G\to K^*$ to be a function such that $f(gh)=f(g)g(f(h))$ for all $g,h\in G$.
>
> Then there exists a $k\in K$ such that $f(g)=g(k)/k$ for all $g.$ Dedekind lemma shows $b=\sum_{h\in G}f(h)h(c)\neq 0$ for some $c$. Then $$f(g)g(b)=\sum_{h\in G}f(g)g(f(h))gh(c)=\sum_{g\in G}f(gh)gh(c)=b.$$
> Thus $f(g)=g(b^{-1})/b^{-1}$.

I am confused since $F$ does not appear in the final statement here and is Galois condition being used anywhere?

Comment: Do you have a proposed formulation for the non-Galois case?

Comment: @Lubin If we take $K/F$ to be a non-Galois finite extension, $G=Gal(K/F)$, we can also define crossed homomorphism, the statement would be any function $f:G\to K^*$ such that $f(gh)=f(g)g(f(h))$ can be written as $f(g)=g(b)/b$ for some $b\in K^*$. I think this still holds because the lemma on independence of characters still hold.

Comment: Mmm, if $h$ maps $K$ outside itself, how do you define $g\circ h$?

Comment: @Lubin But $Gal(K/F)$ means automorphisms of $K$ over $F$? So it always maps $K$ into $K$. Maybe the proposition doesn't need Galois anywhere, because $F$ does not appear in the final statement.

Comment: Oh, sorry, for me, $\text{Gal}(K/F)$ is the Galois set of $F$-morphisms of $K$ into an algebraically closed extension. For your concept of Gal, you’d just have to sit down and carefully prove what you hope to be true.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks for clarifying the two definitions! But we only need the extension to be normal, not separable by your definition?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I’m always rather sloppy about inseparability. I still feel that the Galois set is always defined, but you need normal and separable for it to do you any good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, only the data "a finite group of automorphisms of K" is needed, the field F appears only as the fixed field of G, it plays no role in the proof. You can find such a statement (and its proof) e.g. in Artin-Tate's "Class field theory", Benjamin 1968, p. 202.